# How to check if list item sits between tuples in another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, lambda

I'm trying to return a pair of tuples in a list when an item in another list is numerically in-between them. I've looked through the site for help, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works/can be adapted for me.

Firstly consider the two lists below:

```
my_list = [1.5, 1.2, 1.1]
min_max = [(1.1, 1.4), (1.0, 1.3), (1.6, 1.8)]
```

I need each item in *my_list* to iterate through each pair of tuples in the *min_max* list, returning a pair when it sits within that range. Using the data from *my_list*, it would return:

```
(1.1, 1.4)
(1.0, 1.3)
```

Note that although both 1.2, and 1.1 both fall between (1.0, 1.3), I only need it to return once. Progress wise: I can iterate through a list when the range is fixed using the *lambda* function and I tried expanding it with list iteration, but I can't get it to work

```
list_return = filter(lambda x: 1.1 <= x <= 1.5, my_list)
[i for i in my_list]
print (list_return)
```

I've tried all sorts of variations, and i'm beginning to wonder if i'm approaching this correctly?

Comment: "but I can't get it to work" What is different between what you actually get, and what you want to get?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you returned (1.0, 1.3) once and not twice? do you need to compare a unique tuple each time?

Comment: hello @SachinReddy, first of all, welcome to stackoverflow. You could help us to help you, by providing the reproducable code, the output and the wished output, (well the stuffs that is descripted in [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response guys! I opted for L. MacKenzie's answer. I will be more clear in future by providing code, output and desired output. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are stuck trying to iterate through `my_list`, but this is simpler to iterate through `min_max` and check if any values in `my_list` are between each pair. This is working for me.

```
result = [(a, b) for a, b in min_max if any(a <= item <= b for item in my_list)]
print(result)
```

And I get

```
[(1.1, 1.4), (1.0, 1.3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
my_list = [1.5, 1.2, 1.1]
min_max = [(1.1, 1.4), (1.0, 1.3), (1.6, 1.8)]
for i in[i for i in min_max if list(filter(lambda x: min(i) <= x <= max(i), my_list))]:
    print(i)
```

That will output

```
(1.1, 1.4)
(1.0, 1.3)
```